# Getting first n unique elements from Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, generator, unique

I have a python list where elements can repeat.

```
>>> a = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to get the first `n` unique elements from the list.
So, in this case, if i want the first 5 unique elements, they would be:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I have come up with a solution using generators:

```
def iterate(itr, upper=5):

    count = 0
    for index, element in enumerate(itr):
        if index==0:
            count += 1
            yield element

        elif element not in itr[:index] and count<upper:
            count += 1
            yield element
```

In use:

```
>>> i = iterate(a, 5)
>>> [e for e in i]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I have doubts on this being the most optimal solution. Is there an alternative strategy that i can implement to write it in a more pythonic and efficient 
way?

Comment: Try: `set(a)[:n]`

Comment: @TonyPellerin Oh, I just saw your comment right after I answered.

Comment: @xssChauhan i think your implementation is good. being verbose is good.

Comment: @TonyPellerin does not guarantee you get the first 5 elements

Comment: Your code is Pythonic enough, it is just inefficient. `element not in itr[:index]` is not efficient, use a set

Comment: Is the list always sorted?

Comment: for the future: if your code works and you need to improve it, it is better to post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order)

Comment: From the title and description, I was expecting to select the elements which only appear exactly once in `a` : `1, 4, 5, 6`. So the request would fail with `n=5`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I would use a `set` to remember what was seen and return from the generator when you have `seen` enough:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    
def get_unique_N(iterable, N):
    """Yields (in order) the first N unique elements of iterable. 
    Might yield less if data too short."""
    seen = set()
    for e in iterable:
        if e in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(e)
        yield e
        if len(seen) == N:
            return
            
k = get_unique_N([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4)
print(list(k))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

According to [PEP-479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) you should `return` from generators, not `raise StopIteration` - thanks to [@khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) & [@iBug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5958455/ibug) for that piece of comment - one never learns out.

With 3.6 you get a deprecated warning, with 3.7 it gives RuntimeErrors: [Transition Plan](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/#transition-plan) if still using `raise StopIteration`

---

Your solution using `elif element not in itr[:index] and count<upper:` uses `O(k)` lookups - with `k` being the length of the slice - using a set reduces this to `O(1)` lookups but uses  more memory because the set has to be kept as well. It is a speed vs. memory tradeoff - what is better is application/data dependend.

Consider `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]` vs `[1] * 1000 + [2] * 1000 + [3] * 1000 + [4] * 1000 + [5] * 1000 + [6]`:

For 6 uniques (in longer list):

- you would have lookups of `O(1)+O(2)+...+O(5001)`
- mine would have `5001*O(1)` lookup + memory for `set( {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})`

Comment: Instead of `if e in seen: continue`, `yield e` and `return`, you could also just `return list(seen)` at the end.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That would not guarantee that the items returned would be in the same order they were encountered.

Comment: yielding in order :) list(set) not

Comment: Isn't there something like an ordered set?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yeah, sure, but no built-in ones. You can always use an `OrderedDict` like a set, or just a plain `dict` in Python 3.7+

Answer (score 25):

You can adapt the popular [`itertools` `unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def unique_everseen_limit(iterable, limit=5):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    for element in iterable:
        if element not in seen:
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
        if len(seen) == limit:
            break

a = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6]

res = list(unique_everseen_limit(a))  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Alternatively, as suggested by @Chris_Rands, you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to extract a fixed number of values from a non-limited generator:

```
from itertools import islice

def unique_everseen(iterable):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    for element in iterable:
        if element not in seen:
            seen_add(element)
            yield element

res = list(islice(unique_everseen(a), 5))  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Note the `unique_everseen` recipe is available in 3rd party libraries via [`more_itertools.unique_everseen`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen) or [`toolz.unique`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.unique), so you could use:

```
from itertools import islice
from more_itertools import unique_everseen
from toolz import unique

res = list(islice(unique_everseen(a), 5))  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
res = list(islice(unique(a), 5))           # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: The alternative would be creating an infinite generator and then `itertools.islice(gen, limit)`

Comment: Why not drop line 3 in you first block of code and do `seen.add(element)` instead?

Comment: @jorijnsmit, It's an optimosation. One less lookup in each iteration of the for loop. You should notice the difference in very large loops.

Comment: This 2nd solution is the fastest one as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67391971/3243159).

Answer (score 9):

If your objects are [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) (`int`s are hashable) you can write utility function using [`fromkeys` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) of [`collections.OrderedDict` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (or starting from *Python3.7* a plain `dict`, since they became [officially](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html) ordered) like

```
from collections import OrderedDict


def nub(iterable):
    """Returns unique elements preserving order."""
    return OrderedDict.fromkeys(iterable).keys()
```

and then implementation of `iterate` can be simplified to

```
from itertools import islice


def iterate(itr, upper=5):
    return islice(nub(itr), upper)
```

or if you want always a `list` as an output

```
def iterate(itr, upper=5):
    return list(nub(itr))[:upper]
```

## Improvements

As @Chris_Rands mentioned this solution walks through entire collection and we can improve this by writing `nub` utility in a form of [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) like others already did:

```
def nub(iterable):
    seen = set()
    add_seen = seen.add
    for element in iterable:
        if element in seen:
            continue
        yield element
        add_seen(element)
```

Comment: I was thinking of this, definitely short, but it is O(N)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Pythonic approach using `itertools.takewhile()`:

```
In [95]: from itertools import takewhile

In [96]: seen = set()

In [97]: set(takewhile(lambda x: seen.add(x) or len(seen) <= 4, a))
Out[97]: {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: By which definition is this abuse of the `or` operator considered *Pythonic*?

Comment: @cdlane  By the definition in which this use of `or` is misuse.

Comment: I think a proper function should be used instead of a lambda. Here the `seen.add` is not returning a boolean value, and still being used for truth checking. Your implementation saves us writing a generator function, which is welcome suggestion. But the `predicate` function should be more explicit.

Comment: We've different concepts of *Pythonic*: [To be Pythonic is to use the Python constructs and data structures with clean, readable idioms.](https://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html)

Comment: I disagree this is Pythonic, `seen.add or len(seen) <= 4` shouldn't be used in a function like `takewhile`, for the smae reasons you wouldn't use it in `map` or `filter`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `OrderedDict` or, since Python 3.7, an ordinary `dict`, since they are implemented to preserve the insertion order. Note that this won't work with sets.

```
N = 3
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
d = {x: True for x in a}
list(d.keys())[:N]
```

Comment: In 3.6 order-preserving `dict`s were an implementation detail (in the reference implementation... not sure how alternative interpreters handled it). It wasn't official until 3.7.

Comment: I think `d = dict.fromkeys(a)` would be better.

Answer (score 5):

There are really amazing answers for this question, which are fast, compact and brilliant! The reason I am putting here this code is that I believe there are plenty of cases when you don't care about 1 microsecond time loose nor you want additional libraries in your code for one-time solving a simple task.

```
a = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6]
res = []
for x in a:
    if x not in res:  # yes, not optimal, but doesnt need additional dict
        res.append(x)
        if len(res) == 5:
            break
print(res)
```

Comment: me likey. straight forward, verbose, and with a few less lines.

Comment: Use `set` rather than `list` for O(1) lookup.

Comment: @teng ... inefficient.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, this is inefficient, I agree. Lists are not well suited for search operations (like `in` does), better use dictionaries. In fact I just participated for fun. But, to mention, there are certain cases when simple and understandable code matters, like educational purposes

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga inefficient compared to... OP's implementation?

Comment: @teng similarly inefficient.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga gotcha! ;) amazing this post got so much attention :p

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Justification is good - you will need additional dictionary for that, and that increases the line number. That what I meant, of course not operator itself

Comment: @grapes but this is time-inefficient. Also, who cares about the line numbers? Do you suffer from a lack of lines? Didn'tsee your response to me. Yes, I agree, this implementation would work and is at least correct. I didn't downvote, btw.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I know, i know, the best answer is using `set()`, as mentioned by other participants. I am not pretending this code to be the fastest, just compact and understandable. This simple question produced so much rush that I couldn't withstand a desire to participate

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yah just to be clear, I down voted for the reasons given above. Plus, this is not just a micro-optimisation, it will make a large difference for medium sized data sets (and there is no reason to avoid imports from the standard library)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the elements are ordered as shown, this is an opportunity to have fun with the `groupby` function in itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice

def first_unique(data, upper):
    return islice((key for (key, _) in groupby(data)), 0, upper)

a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]

print(list(first_unique(a, 5)))
```

Updated to use `islice` instead of `enumerate` per @juanpa.arrivillaga.  You don't even need a `set` to keep track of duplicates.

Comment: You might as well use `islice`

Comment: So `groupby` retains order, nice, but is it an implementation detail or a feature?

Comment: @kubanczyk, yes `groupby` is mostly used with sorted data, where it becomes an aggregator.  If the OP's data weren't sorted, `groupby` wouldn't work for this problem.  However, `groupy` can be used with unsorted data to solve some other problems.  In that case it can be used to detect when data changes.

Answer (score 4):

Using `set` with `sorted+ key`

```
sorted(set(a), key=list(a).index)[:5]
Out[136]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This is inefficient.

Comment: @xssChauhan this *will* return it in order, but this is inefficient O(n^2 * log n) I believe. You can do this in O(N)

Answer (score 4):

**Given**

```
import itertools as it


a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**Code**

A simple list comprehension (similar to @cdlane's answer).

```
[k for k, _ in it.groupby(a)][:5]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Alternatively, in Python 3.6+:

```
list(dict.fromkeys(a))[:5]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Profiling Analysis

### Solutions

Which solution is the fastest? There are two clear favorite answers (and 3 solutions) that captured most of the votes.

1. The [solution by Patrick Artner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53887841/3243159) - denoted as PA.
2. The [first solution by jpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53887868/3243159) - denoted as jpp1
3. The [second solution by jpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53887868/3243159) - denoted as jpp2

This is because these claim to run in O(N) while others here run in O(N^2), or do not guarantee the order of the returned list.

### Experiment setup

For this experiment 3 variables were considered.

1. N elements. The number of first N elements the function is searching for.
2. List length. The longer the list the further the algorithm has to look to find the last element.
3. Repeat limit. How many times an element can repeat before the next element occurs in the list. This is uniformly distributed between 1 and the repeat limit.

The assumptions for data generation were as follows. How strict these are depend on the algorithm used, but is more a note on how the data was generated than a limitation on the algorithms themselves.

1. The elements never occur again after its repeated sequence first appears in the list.
2. The elements are numeric and increasing.
3. The elements are of type int.

So in a list of [1,1,1,2,2,3,4 ....] 1,2,3 would never appear again. The next element after 4 would be 5, but there could be a random number of 4s up to the repeat limit before we see 5.

A new dataset was created for each combination of variables and and re-generated 20 times. The python `timeit` function was used to profile the algorithms 50 times on each dataset. The mean time of the 20x50=1000 runs (for each combination) were reported here. Since the algorithms are generators, their outputs were converted to a list to get the execution time.

### Results

As is expected the more elements searched for, the longer it takes. This graph shows that the execution time is indeed O(N) as claimed by the authors (the straight line proves this).

[image: Fig 1. Varying the first N elements searched for.]

**Fig 1. Varying the first N elements searched for.**

All three solutions do not consume additional computation time beyond that which is required. The below image shows what happens when the list is limited in size, and not N elements. Lists of length 10k, with elements repeating a maximum of 100 times (and thus on average repeating 50 times) would on average run out of unique elements by 200 (10000/50). If any of these graphs showed an increase in computation time beyond 200 this would be a cause for concern.

[image: Fig 2. The effect of first N elements chosen > number of unique elements.]

**Fig 2. The effect of first N elements chosen > number of unique elements.**

The figure below again shows that processing time increases (at a rate of O(N)) the more data the algorithm has to sift through. The rate of increase is the same as when first N elements were varied. This is because stepping through the list is the common execution block in both, and the execution block that ultimately decides how fast the algorithm is.

[image: Fig 3. Varying the repeat limit.]

**Fig 3. Varying the repeat limit.**

### Conclusion

The [2nd solution posted by jpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53887868/3243159) is the fastest solution of the 3 in all cases. The solution is only slightly faster than the [solution posted by Patrick Artner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53887841/3243159), and is almost twice as fast as [his first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53887868/3243159).

Comment: This is very useful information. Would it also be possible to add a memory consumption analysis? That way a user could also make a decision considering both their constraints.

Comment: I agree, however in this case the information stored in all 3 of the functions are very similar. Furthermore, the dataset processed will be much larger than the information stored, so the memory used by the function is negligible in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something like this?

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(set(a))[:5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: If order is not a strict requirement, then this works.   Keep in mind, sets are unordered.

Comment: This is wrong as it may or may not return the _first_ five unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

## Example list:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

## Function returns all or count of unique items needed from list

1st argument - list to work with, 2nd argument (optional) - count of unique items (by default - None - it means that all unique elements will be returned)

```
def unique_elements(lst, number_of_elements=None):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(lst))[:number_of_elements]
```

Here is example how it works. List name is "a", and we need to get 2 unique elements:

```
print(unique_elements(a, 2))
```

## Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6]

from collections import defaultdict
def function(lis,n):
    dic = defaultdict(int)

    sol=set()

    for i in lis:
            try:
                if dic[i]:
                    pass
                else:
                    sol.add(i)
                    dic[i]=1
                    if len(sol)>=n:
                        break
            except KeyError:
                pass

    return list(sol)

print(function(a,3))
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3]
```