# How to select first 3 distinct values in a column

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to select the first 3 distinct points in a column excluding the first 0 point. I need distinct points to perform polynomial regression.

My_column:

```
  A = np.array([0, 0.5, 0, 0 ,1.0, 2.0])
```

Expected:

```
  B = np.array([0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0])
```

Essentially I want to skip over one 0 and select the 1.0 instead.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Demonstrate this with code and highlight the exact problem you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting first n unique elements from Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887803/getting-first-n-unique-elements-from-python-list)

Comment: @sophros i tried to manually do an if statement to check if the previous number at location [i] == to the current number at location [i+1]. But i am unable to select it and i am not sure how to move on from here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0, 0.5, 0, 0 ,1.0, 2.0])
B = A[0]
B = np.append(B, list(set(A[1:]))[:3])
print(B)
```

Comment: thanks! but i am having an error. TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: `set` does not maintain the order of elements from `A`. It seems to me that your solution does not answer the OT's question.